# Trying to resize an image twice in a function and it's only resizing it once

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

I'm trying to have a user upload a file and then my function will resize that photo to something like 800x600 and then resize that file to 165x165. With my code, it's only resizing it to 165x165, but if I comment that section out, it resizes it to 800x600.

What can I do to get it to resize both?

```
   /**
    * addPhoto - function which shows the add photo page
    */
    function addPhoto($album)
    {   
        $album = rawurldecode($album);

        ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '4M');  
        ini_set('post_max_size', '12M');  
        ini_set('max_input_time', 300);  
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/photoAlbums/'.$album.'/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|pjpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '4096';   // that's 4MBs
        $config['max_width'] = '4000';
        $config['max_height'] = '3000';
        $config['remove_space'] = TRUE;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) { // if there are errors uploading the file...
            $content_data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());


        } else {    // else there are NO errors, we need to resize it, and ditch that huge ass original


        $image = $this->upload->data(); 
        $uploadedFile = $image['file_name'];

        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $thumbConfig['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $thumbConfig['source_image'] = $image['full_path']; 
        $thumbConfig['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $thumbConfig['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $thumbConfig['width'] = 800;
        $thumbConfig['height'] = 600;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($thumbConfig);

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }

        $this->image_lib->clear();

        $thumbConfig['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $thumbConfig['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
        $thumbConfig['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $thumbConfig['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $thumbConfig['width'] = 165;
        $thumbConfig['height'] = 165;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($thumbConfig);

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }

        $content_data['firstName'] = $this->session->userdata('firstName');
        $data['sess'] = $this->session;
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('member/addPhoto_success', $content_data, true);
        $this->load->view('template/admin', $data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the second time running the image_lib, you're going to want to avoid overwriting the file by specifying the new file for it to create:
after:

```
$thumbConfig['height'] = 165;
```

add:

```
$thumbConfig['new_image'] = $image['file_path'] . "thumb_" . $image['file_name'];
```

so if your resized 800 x 600 image resides at /my/upload/path/foo.jpg,
this will create a thumb at /my/upload/path/thumb_foo.jpg.

Comment: Really late to the party here, but the user guide says that the "create_thumb" settings will create a thumbnail (AND PRESERVE THE ORIGINAL).  Why must you specify the new_image in this case?  Should the existance of "create_thumb" do that for us?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create two new resized images and leave the original intact, you need to add

```
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
```

or

```
$config['new_image'] = '/path/to/new_image.jpg';
```

to the first section.

According to your code, you will overwrite the original file with an 800x600 version and then create a 165x165 thumbnail.

Comment: I read my code as it would resize the uploaded pic to 800x600, then take that image as the source and create a thumb 165x165 based on the 800x600 file since I have create_thumb = true in my second config. In either case, new_image was the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this line on the first resize:

```
$thumbConfig['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
```

Comment: I actually have that line in my code, I must have accidently erased it when I was deleted my comments while posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I just ran into the same issue.

```
$config['create_thumb'] = true
```

did not create a new file.

Adding the thumb marker configuration:

```
$config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb'
```

worked.

It seems that `_thumb` is not the default for `thumb_marker`.